# Firefox jquery position() off by 1px

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

For some reason my elements are sometimes off by 1px using jquery position() when doing calculations on the x-axis.  I tried using Math.ceil() but did not seem to help.  I'm looking for a cross-browser solution if anyone has any ideas.  I'm using Firefox/3.6.13 on a mac.

```
var obj = $('#test'), dd = $('#dd');

obj.click(function(){
    dd.css({
        'left': obj.position().left - (dd.outerWidth() - obj.outerWidth()),
        'top': obj.position().top + (obj.outerHeight() - 2)
    });   
});
```

​
Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/WmJgZ/

I'm trying to align the button and div to the right.

Anyone have any ideas or know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `margin: 0;` on `#test` like this
http://jsfiddle.net/sguillope/WmJgZ/3/

Comment: Hey thanks Sly, that's seems to work great for Chrome & Safari, but im still getting 1px extra on the dd.outerWidth() in firefox.  Any more ideas?

Comment: @seogrady Sorry I have no idea :(

Comment: Thanks for trying! It's actually 1px extra on obj.outerWidth() -- 37px -- [the button] in firefox. But when you take a screen shot its 36px???? :-(

Comment: I looked into it and it appears that firefox on mac renders text so that outerWidth() is 1px off so you need to add 1px.  For now i'm just going to use $.browser.mozilla to add extra 1px :-)